# Problema en consulta a BD con tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos, select

Buenos días. Tengo dos tablas, sesiones y usuarios.

Un campo de la tabla sesiones está relacionado con un campo de la tabla usuarios (el campo "usuario" de ambos).

En la tabla "usuarios" habrán usuarios que no tendrán ningún valor en el campo "num_accesos" de la tabla sesiones, por tanto lo que quiero es mostrar la tabla "usuarios" entera junto con el campo "num_accesos" de la otra tabla, aunque hayan usuarios que no tengan este campo.

Hago esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(sesiones.num_accesos) as num_accesos, 
    usuarios.usuario, 
    usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.centro 
FROM sesiones 
INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.usuario = sesiones.usuario 
GROUP BY usuarios.usuario
```

Y me muestra solo los usuarios que tienen valor en el campo "num_accesos", es decir, solo me muestra los usuarios que están presentes en la tabla "sesiones".

¿Como puedo hacer para mostrar la tabla "usuarios" aunque tengan el campo "num_accesos" en blanco?

He probado a cambiar la tabla en el FROM pero no funciona tampoco.

Saludos.

Comment: Has intentado `RIGHT JOIN`?

Comment: *lo que quiero es mostrar la tabla "usuarios" entera junto con el campo "num_accesos" de la otra tabla, aunque hayan usuarios que no tengan este campo*  ahí está la clave de la respuesta. En el FROM debes tener la tabla `usuarios` no la tabla `sesiones` y usar `LEFT JOIN` para que muestre  los usuarios que no tengan correspondencias en `sesiones`. Es exactamente lo que ha respondido @NachoBiencinto

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Has probado a invertir el orden de las tablas en la consulta?

Pides TODOS los usuarios, y recuperas la info de sesion solo de los que la tengan.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(sesiones.num_accesos) as num_accesos, 
    usuarios.usuario, 
    usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.centro 
FROM usuarios 
    LEFT JOIN 
        sesiones 
    ON usuarios.usuario = sesiones.usuario GROUP BY usuarios.usuario
```